# Trouble in changing the color for different paths

Tags: java, swing

i have two paths in paintComponent and i am setting different color for both paths.And it is confirmed that i am getting different colors through my own defined method and variable but both paths get the same color.
This is how my paintComponents looks like.

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    for (int i = 0; i < arrays.size(); i++) {
        g2.setColor(arrays.get(i).getColor());
        temp = arrays.get(i).getArrayList();
        path.moveTo(temp.get(0).x, temp.get(0).y);
        for (int j = 1; j < temp.size(); j++) {
            path.moveTo(temp.get(j).x, temp.get(j).y);
        }
        g2.draw(path);
    }

    if(select) {
        g2.setColor(selectedCircleColor);
        path.moveTo(point.get(0).x, point.get(0).y);
        for (int i = 1; i < point.size(); i++) {
            path.lineTo(point.get(i).x, point.get(i).y);
        }
        g2.draw(path);
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't forget the `super.paintComponent(g)` at the start of the method. Post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: i have super.paintComponent(g) in my program,not in the question though

Comment: What is the point of posting random code??? How do we know the rest of your code is actually in your program??? The code you post should be the code you are executing. Actually the code you post should be a `SSCCE` that demonstrates the problem if you want help. Since you haven't posted a SSCCE you haven't gotten any help.